# Navigating CraueFormFlowBundle when editing existing entity

Tags: forms, symfony, twig, craueformflow

I created a multipage form using [CraueFormFlowBundle](https://github.com/craue/CraueFormFlowBundle). With this form I can create a new entity object or edit an existing one.

I then added the setting

```
protected $allowDynamicStepNavigation = true;
```

to allow navigating back and forth through the form's pages, however when using the form to edit an existing object I want to be able to jump straight to any page in the form. This does not seem to work - the object data is loaded and I can press next repeatedly until I get to the desired page.
Is there a way to render the page navigation when editing using CraueFormFlowBundle ?

My template includes:

```
{% include 'CraueFormFlowBundle:FormFlow:stepList.html.twig' %}
```

to create the navigation. Here is the editAction:

```
    public function editDriverAction($id) {

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $formData = $em->getRepository('NewgtDriverBundle:NewgtDriver')->find($id);

    if (!$formData) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Driver.');
    }

    //$formData = new NewgtDriver(); // Your form data class. Has to be an object, won't work properly with an array.

    $flow = $this->get('newgtDriver.form.flow.createDriver'); // must match the flow's service id
    $flow->bind($formData);

    // form of the current step
    $form = $flow->createForm();
    if ($flow->isValid($form)) {
        $flow->saveCurrentStepData($form);

        if ($flow->nextStep()) {
            // form for the next step
            $form = $flow->createForm();
        } else {
            // flow finished
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($formData);
            $em->flush();

            $flow->reset(); // remove step data from the session

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('driver')); // redirect when done
        }
    }

    return $this->render('NewgtDriverBundle:Driver:new.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'flow' => $flow,
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[In the source code](https://github.com/craue/CraueFormFlowBundle/blob/master/Resources/views/FormFlow/stepList_content.html.twig) we see that the flow class must override the method loadStepDescriptions.

My FromFlow Class is like:

```
namespace MyBundle\Form\Proposal;

use Craue\FormFlowBundle\Form\FormFlow;

class ProposalFlow extends FormFlow {

    protected $maxSteps = 5;

    protected $allowDynamicStepNavigation = true;

    protected function loadStepDescriptions() {
        return array(
            'Name',
            'Contract',
            'Filter',
            'Alternative',
            'Summary',
        );
    }
}
```

Hope this help